# JavaScript Confusion with IDs

Tags: javascript

Writing a small browser-based hybrid of Cookie Clicker and A Dark Room.

Gold (the player's score) is displayed onscreen. A set number is added to gold every time a button is clicked. So far, so good. What doesn't work is the logic designed to check if value of gold is greater than 100.

I've worked this over many times, and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Is this a syntax error, or am I missing some additional code?

```
$(function() {
    $('#success')
    var gold = 0;

    // clicked food button adds 3 gold
    $('#food').click(function() {

        gold+=3;
        $('#gold').text(gold);
    });

    // clicked wool button adds 4 gold
    $('#wool').click(function () {

        gold+=4;
        $('#gold').text(gold);
    });

    // clicked lumber button adds 7 gold
    $('#lumber').click(function () {

        gold+=7;
        $('#gold').text(gold);
    });

    // if gold > 99, put
    //alert("You won! Play again?")
    if (('#gold') > 99) {
        var x = confirm("You won! Play again?");
        if (x == true) {
            window.close();
        }
        else {
            window.close();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: look if (('#gold') > 99) { line carefully.

Comment: That code that checks to see if the amount of gold exceeds 99 - when is it supposed to  run? As it is, it only runs once, when the "ready" handler runs.  You need to make that check (and do so correctly) every time that the amount of gold changes.

Comment: I hadn't considered runtime; thanks for addressing that.

@tanaydin I've gone back and forth on the structure of that line, but still couldn't decide what was appropriate. I'm using IDs, so I thought it was appropriate to list gold by its id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you are defining functions but not calling them... try it like this...

```
$(function() {
    // $('#success') // what does this line do ?
    var gold = 0;

    // clicked food button adds 3 gold
    $('#food').click(function() {

        gold+=3;
        $('#gold').text(gold);
        checkGold();
    });

    // clicked wool button adds 4 gold
    $('#wool').click(function () {

        gold+=4;
        $('#gold').text(gold);
        checkGold();
    });

    // clicked lumber button adds 7 gold
    $('#lumber').click(function () {

        gold+=7;
        $('#gold').text(gold);
        checkGold();
    });

    function checkGold() {
        // if gold > 99, put
        //alert("You won! Play again?")
        if (parseInt($('#gold').text()) > 99) {
            var x = confirm("You won! Play again?");
            if (x == true) {
                window.close();
            } else {
                window.close();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you should replace

`if (('#gold') > 99) {`

line with

`if(gold > 99)`

I guess that is =)